# JLabel Icon won't change within package images (Netbeans)

Tags: button, netbeans, icons, jlabel, imageicon

So I have this two images(.png) on my app package, and I want to change a JLabel's icon A to Icon B once  the user clicks the original icon. The problem is, once the label i clicked, the image disappears and a text show's up instead ("jLabel1"). Here's the code for the listener:

```
private void login_IngresarBMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt){                                             
    String imageName = "login_buttonHighlight.png";
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(imageName);
    icon.getImage().flush();
    login_IngresarB.setIcon(icon);     
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, I found the answer, used getResourse() instead of just the image name:

```
String imageName = "login_buttonHighlight.png";
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(imageName);
```

For this one:

```
ImageIcon nuevo = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("login_buttonHighlight.png"));
```